# How do I export a ggplot as resizable image?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a report with some coworkers in Google Docs (which will eventually be printed). We want to include some plots generated with ggplot. As we edit the document, the space for the images keeps changing slightly--often, we need to resize and/or change the aspect ratio of a plot slightly so that it fits on the page with the accompanying text.

Is there a way to export a ggplot object to an image that is resizable in the same way that plots can be resized in the Export dialog in RStudio?

Google Docs does not support SVG images--dropping an svg on the page simply opens the SVG itself (rather than adding it to the doc), so that's not an option.

Comment: Is this only `ggplot2` specific problem? I guess it happens with base R too?

Comment: I suspect not, the grid graphics resizes elements dynamically, e.g. making the device window 2x as big will make the axis title text (and space reserved for this) not 2x as big. I don't think there exists a format which you can export to that preserves the grid behaviour.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/107705 suggests that the `.emf` format worked at some point, no idea if it still does.

Comment: I suspect it's not necessarily ggplot2-specific, but I rarely export base graphics and don't understand the underlying differences (if any?) in how base plots differ from ggplots once they're generated.

Comment: I just tried `.emf`. This is a workable solution if our doc was in Microsoft Word (needed to fiddle with the image a bit, but it will resize nicely). Unfortunately, it looks `.emf` support is gone from Google Docs presently (June 2020).

Comment: What about `.svg`? If you're exporting ggplot objects, the `ggsave()` function does include support for that format.  Just not sure what formats are accepted in Google docs.

Comment: That's exactly it--Google Docs doesn't support `.svg`, unfortunately. Neither does MS Word, so it's a non-starter at least as of June 2020.

Comment: Does Google Docs support PDF as image?